# Split VAT into segments based on Country code

Tags: php, regex

What is the best wat to split any `VAT number` into segments?
First part is the country code, is always 2 alphanumeric.
Second is the remaining number.

For example:
`NL820471616B01` should be split to `NL` and `820471616B01`

`BE0824148721` should be split to `BE` and `0824148721`

`ATU12345678` should be split to `AT` and `U12345678`

I have tried this but that will only suit when there are 2 alphanumeric numbers.

```
$vat_clean = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $_GET['vat']);
$vat_country = substr($vat_clean,2,25);
$vat_code = substr($vat_clean,2);
```

Comment: You need a Regular Expression so you can match the characters, with variable length

Comment: Which VAT numbers start with U?

Comment: I was checking https://www.gov.uk/guidance/vat-eu-country-codes-vat-numbers-and-vat-in-other-languages
There is Austria and starts with `AT` not with `U` the `U` is used after  `AT` Sorry!

Comment: Your original spec was ___First part is the country code, can be 1,2 or 3 alphanumeric___ PLease if you change your mind expect some answers that no loger match your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appeared the any VAT number starts with 2 alphanumeric numbers I could tweak the existing code to get it fully to work.

```
$vat_clean = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $_GET['vat']);
$vat_country = substr($vat_clean,2,15);
$vat_code = substr($vat_clean,0,2);
```

Comment: In case this is an answer, please mention why it works. If this is an edit to the question, do it by adding contents in the original question or as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You might use 2 capturing groups

```
\b([A-Z]{2})([A-Z0-9]+)\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `([A-Z]{2})` Capture **group 1**, match 2 uppercase chars A-Z
- `([A-Z0-9]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ chars A-Z0-9
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQSTQX/1)

```
$re = '/\b([A-Z]{2})([A-Z0-9]+)\b/';
$str = 'NL820471616B01';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // NL
echo $matches[2]; // 820471616B01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)/", "u1236777", $matches);
print("Sring: " . $matches[1] . "\n");//u
print("Int: " . $matches[2] . "\n");//1236777

//*******//

preg_match("/([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)/", "NL820471616B01", $matches);
print("Sring: " . $matches[1] . "\n");//NL
print("Int: " . $matches[2] . "\n");//820471616B01
```

We can run a regular expression that will split the string and number

Comment: I have edited my post based on the comments.

Comment: `preg_match("/([a-zA-Z]{2}+)(\\d+)/", "OOY820471616B01", $matches);
print("Sring: " . $matches[1] . "\n");
print("Int: " . $matches[2] . "\n");`

What do you want to happen if the string contains more than 2 characters?
you can cut to last 2 digits.

Comment: Sorry the OP decided to change his Spec, ignore my comments